# accessing classes from a directory without knowing directory content

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

If I'm provided an address to a directory, but I have no information regarding what is within the directory, can I check to see if the directory contains any classes and access the classes via `URLClassLoader`.

I'm currently creating a URL array with the address of the directory:

```
URL [] urls = new URL[1];
urls[0] = new File(address).toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

However, even with this approach, I can't access classes from the `URLClassLoader` object since I don't know what the classes are called, right?

Comment: How about [walking the file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and load each ".class" file you find?

Comment: You are correct that Java intentionally does not provide a way to enumerate the classes in a package. There is a Guava utility that peeks into the loader, gets the directory, and enumerates the .class files for you.

Comment: I’m not sure why you need this, but I suspect you would be better served by having discoverable classes implement an interface, and making that interface a service provider interface, as described in the [ServiceLoader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you are likely to get is [The Guava ClassPath class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html). However, this works by peeking into the URLClassLoader and then talking to the file system.

Comment: So `getAllClasses` returns a set of all the classes in the directory?

Comment: Yes, with caveats. Read the source.